# How to make a backend using Python & Flask for my Flutter app?

Tags: python, flutter, flask, backend

Some context information about me: I am new to app development, in fact the first framework I am learning right now to create my app is flutter using dart. I also used to work with Python 3 (never with Flask nor Django, but I am willing to learn).

For my backend, I know that if my app doesn't die at an early stage, I will have to skip Firestore and make my own solution.

QUESTIONS :

- How did you learn backend?
- What resources do you recommend to learn backend with python that are best suited to my case ? (please, no generic answer)
- any advice on how to approach this problem ?

In advance, thank you very much for going out of your way and answering my not so clever questions.

Comment: SO is a place to ask about specific bugs and problems. Please look up tutorials, ask on reddit or stackexchange

Comment: @Dani I am well aware of SO guidelines, even though it may seem like an open-ended question, it is not. I asked specific ones based on experience and not on opinion.
SO, is not exclusively about bug fixes.

Comment: @Dani https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/
https://stackoverflow.com/help
Have a good reading.

Answer (score 0):

I used py4web https://py4web.com/ which is based off of bottle. They have pretty good documentation and it's super intuitive and powerful. Only way to keep practicing! Recommend checking out some web dev course for the best results